# Attempting to create a connection between two models in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models, Event and Profile.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    event_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank = 'TRUE', primary_key='TRUE')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = 'TRUE')

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    eventList = models.ManyToManyField(Event)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have a page with a bunch of events and next to each is a button. Upon clicking the button, I want the event to be added to the user's "eventList". The current approach is to assign the button the value of the "event_id" and pass it as a parameter to a dajaxice function (not 100% sure this is the best approach). The dajaxice function is located in a file called ajax.py and looks like this:

```
from search.models import Event
from profiles.models import Profile
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register
def addEvent(event):
    e = Event.objects.get(pk=event)
    u = user.get_profile.eventList
    u.add(e)
    return
```

Just by looking, I can tell that it's very wrong and that the issue is most likely with my function and the way I'm appending to the eventList. Anyone have any ideas on an approach to this?

Comment: What looks wrong about this?  Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like `user.get_profile` would fail because `get_profile` is a function.

You need to call it.

```
dajaxice_register
def addEvent(event):
    e = Event.objects.get(pk=event)
    u = user.get_profile().eventList
    u.add(e)
    return
```

More importantly though, you need to find ways to debug your code. It's not always going to be this easy.

Comment: Changed it how you said. I can't check if it works though. When I log into the admin and attempt to look at a user's profile from there, I get a "(1146, "Table 'eventsearch.profiles_profile_eventList' doesn't exist")" error. I've sync'd my database and all, but can't seem to look at all.

Comment: @user2411268, you need to fix that. You must have added eventList m2m after the fact. Drop the table and start over, or use `manage.py sqlall` and determine the SQL you need to create the m2m table